# Number of orthonormal vectors is finite without Bessel's inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

I want to show that if $\{e_\alpha\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space $H$, then the set $\{\alpha: \langle v, e_\alpha\rangle > 1\}$ is finite for any $v \in H$. This is immediately true by Bessel's inequality, but I was told to not use Bessel's inequality or any of its corollaries. With this condition, I'm not sure where to begin.

I've thought about considering the functional $f(x) = \langle v, x \rangle$ and maybe showing its operator norm is infinite, but I can't see where to go from here.

Comment: What are you allowed to use if not Bessel?

Comment: I have to echo @NickF's comment... and, srsly, I guess you're being asked to reprove a very special/weak version of Bessel's inequality. So just degrade the proof of Bessel's inequality so that it proves less... :) :)

Comment: @paulgarrett That's fair enough and what I plan to do anyways. I was just hoping if there's some other slick proof that doesn't ultimately reiterate Bessel's inequality.

Comment: @Dalop, I think Bessel's inequality is sooooo basic that's it's hard to "get basic-er" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes... assume that $\{\alpha : \langle v,e_\alpha\rangle =1\}$ is infinite and extract a sequence $(\alpha_n)_n$ of such indices $\alpha$.

Consider the vector $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n e_{\alpha_n} \in H$, it is easy to show that this series converges since the sequence of its partial sums is Cauchy. But we then have
$$\left\langle v,\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n e_{\alpha_n}\right\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \underbrace{\langle v,e_{\alpha_n}\rangle}_{> 1} > \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n = +\infty$$
which is a contradiction.